# JavaFX: Different types of alignment in one column of TableView

Tags: javafx, alignment, tableview, cell

Is it possible to do different types of alignment for each cell in one column of `TableView`?

E.g. I have a column with 3 possible types of data inside: positive number, negative number and "-". First should be aligned left, second - right and 3rd - center.

This is what I've tried:

```
private void setPositionAndColor(TableColumn<TransferItem, String> tableColumn){
    tableColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<TransferItem, String>, TableCell<TransferItem, String>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<TransferItem, String> call(TableColumn<TransferItem, String> column) {
            TableCell<TransferItem, String> cell = new TableCell<TransferItem, String>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if (item == null || empty) {
                        setText("");
                    } else {
                        setText(item);
                        if (item.matches("-+\\d.*")) {
                            setTextFill(Color.RED);
                            setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT);
                        }
                        else if (item.equals("-")) {
                            setTextFill(Color.AQUA);
                            setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
                        }else {
                            setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
                            setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        }
    });
}
```

I added color changes just for testing and it works, but alignment doesn't.

Another approach:

```
Pos position;
private void setPositionAndColor(TableColumn<TransferItem, String> tableColumn){
    tableColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<TransferItem, String>, TableCell<TransferItem, String>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<TransferItem, String> call(TableColumn<TransferItem, String> column) {
            TableCell<TransferItem, String> cell = new TableCell<TransferItem, String>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if (item == null || empty) {
                        setText("");
                    } else {
                        setText(item);
                        if (item.matches("-+\\d.*")) {
                            setTextFill(Color.RED);
                            position = Pos.CENTER_RIGHT;
                        }
                        else if (item.equals("-")) {
                            setTextFill(Color.AQUA);
                            position = Pos.CENTER;
                        }else {
                            setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
                            position = Pos.CENTER_LEFT;
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            cell.setAlignment(position);
            return cell;
        }
    });
}
```

Doesn't work either.
Ty for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX TableView text alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455326/javafx-tableview-text-alignment)

Comment: @ eckig  No, I need different types of alignment in one column, not just align whole column one way

Comment: The linked solution works cell based, not column-wise.

Comment: @ eckig  The only difference I see from what I did, those solution uses cell.setStyle("-fx-alignment:...;") instead of cell.setAlignment(Pos....). I tried - didn't work. As I sayed, the code above do changes color for each cell independently, but alignment doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I got a working example - It seems, `setAlignment()` does the trick:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    IntStream.range(0, 1000).mapToObj(Integer::toString).forEach(data::add);

    TableView<String> table = new TableView<String>(data);

    TableColumn<String, String> column = new TableColumn<String, String>("test");
    column.setCellFactory(c -> new TableCell<String,String>(){

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            if(empty) {
                setText(null);
            }
            else {
                setText(item);
                if(getIndex() % 2 == 0) {
                    setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
                }
                else if(getIndex() % 3 == 0) {
                    setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
                }
                else {
                    setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    column.setCellValueFactory(c -> new SimpleStringProperty(c.getValue()));
    table.getColumns().add(column);

    Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(table), 400, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: My god... T.y. very much! (and for editing my English too =) ) I was about to break my brain trying to figure out how Callback und updateItem work running debugger and why my "second approach" acts so strange. And solution was anoter way. Thank you again.