# How to left-justify TableColumn headers programmatically? (i.e. without FXML)

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm trying to left-justify TableColumn headers in JavaFX 17.

I want to do this using Java code ("programmatically").
I do not use FXML.

I can set it globally by supplying a stylesheet on the scene (base64 encoded URL), but how can I change the alignment of just one TableColumn header?

I've tried all manner of CSS via `setStyle(...)`, but all to no avail.

### Here is my preferred solution:

Many, many thanks to @DavidWeber for all his help.
I've incorporated his suggestions.
(and used a JDK switch/null Preview Feature)
The original question code is further down.

```
package com.stackoverflow.question;

import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.skin.TableColumnHeader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public final class TableColumnAlignment extends Application {

    private record RowData(String left, Integer right) {}

    private static final String TITLE_LEFT  = "Left";
    private static final String TITLE_RIGHT = "Right";

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {

        final var colLeft  = buildColumn("colLeft",  TITLE_LEFT,  RowData :: left);
        final var colRight = buildColumn("colRight", TITLE_RIGHT, RowData :: right);
        ;         colRight.setStyle("-fx-alignment: center-right");
        /*
         * TODO See above for TableColumn alignment
         */
        final var sortedList = new SortedList<RowData>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new RowData("Left Column Header should be Left-Justified!", 123456789),
                new RowData("This Cell is left justified ok",                     789),
                new RowData("Right Column Header should be Right-Justified!",  456789) )));

        final var  table    = new TableView<RowData>();
        ;          table.getColumns().add(colLeft);
        ;          table.getColumns().add(colRight);
        ;          table.setItems(sortedList);
        /*
         * Now make sure, when the Table is "unsorted", it reverts to its original order...
         */
        sortedList.comparatorProperty().bind(table.comparatorProperty());
        /*
         * TODO See below for TableColumnHeader alignment
         */
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            table.lookupAll(".column-header > .label").forEach(node -> {
                if (node.getParent()  instanceof  TableColumnHeader
                &&  node              instanceof  Label              nodeLabel) {
                    switch(nodeLabel.getText()) {
                        case TITLE_LEFT  -> nodeLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
                        case TITLE_RIGHT -> nodeLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
                    }
                    System.out.println(nodeLabel + "\t" + nodeLabel.getText());
                }
            });
        });
        stage.setTitle("Table Column Alignment");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(table, 500, 200));
        stage.show();
    }

    private <T, V> TableColumn<T, V> buildColumn(final String id, final String title, final Function<T, V> getter) {

        final var tableColumn = new TableColumn<T, V>(title);
        ;         tableColumn.setId(id);
        ;         tableColumn.setCellValueFactory((cellDataFeatures) -> {

            final T bean              = cellDataFeatures.getValue();
            final V beanPropertyValue = getter.apply(bean);

            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<V>(beanPropertyValue);
        });
        return    tableColumn;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here's the original code for the Question:

```
package com.stackoverflow.question;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public final class TableColumnAlignment extends Application {

    private record RowData(String left, Integer right) {}

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {

        final var       colLeft  = buildTableColumn("Left",  RowData :: left);
        final var       colRight = buildTableColumn("Right", RowData :: right);

        colLeft .setId("colLeft");
        colRight.setId("colRight");
        /*
         * TODO The following sets the Column colour (including Header) but has no effect on alignment
         */
        colLeft.setStyle("-fx-alignment: center-left; -fx-background-color: yellow");

        final var  table    = new TableView<RowData>();
        addColumns(table.getColumns(), colLeft, colRight);
        ;          table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new RowData("Left Column Header should be Left-Justified!", 123456789),
                new RowData("This Cell is left justified ok",                     789),
                new RowData("Right Column Header should be Right-Justified!",  456789) ));

        final var  scene    = new Scene(table, 500, 200);
//      ;          scene.getStylesheets().add(encodeStyleAsURL(".column-header .label {-fx-alignment: center-left}"));
        /*
         * TODO The previous line, when uncommented, left-justifies ALL Column-Headers
         */
        stage.setTitle("Table Column Alignment");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public  static String encodeStyleAsURL(final String cssStyle) {

        final var cssBytes       = cssStyle.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        final var cssBytesBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cssBytes);

        return    "data:text/css;base64," + cssBytesBase64;
    }

    private <T, V> TableColumn<T, V> buildTableColumn(final String title, final Function<T, V> beanPropertyGetter) {

        final var tableColumn = new TableColumn<T, V>(title);
        ;         tableColumn.setCellValueFactory((cellDataFeatures) -> {

            final T bean              = cellDataFeatures.getValue();
            final V beanPropertyValue = beanPropertyGetter.apply(bean);

            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<V>(beanPropertyValue);
        });
        return    tableColumn;
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    private final <T> void addColumns(final ObservableList<TableColumn<T, ?>> columnList, final TableColumn<T, ?>... columns) {
        columnList.addAll(columns);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don’t put answers in the question, put them in an answer.

Comment: I didn't want to distract the credit from David Webers answer! He provided such good help :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Preface**

The solution includes a full working example. There are ways to choose a column header by ID or by text value.

The tricks to know are that JavaFX creates a label inside of the table header cell and that you can find the children of a node with the method `lookup()` or `lookupAll()`.

I refactored your code a little bit, so that there is a minimal example.

**Solution**

This is how it is done:

```
package com.example.demo;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class HelloApplication2 extends Application {

    private record RowData(String left, Integer right) {
    }

    @Override
    public void start(
            Stage stage) {

        TableView<RowData> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setId("myTable");
        table.getColumns().add(buildTableColumn("colLeft", "Left", RowData::left));
        table.getColumns().add(buildTableColumn("colRight", "Right", RowData::right));
        table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new RowData("Left Column Header should be Left-Justified!", 123456789),
                new RowData("This Cell is left justified ok", 789),
                new RowData("Right Column Header should be Right-Justified!", 456789)));

        // Align a column
        alignColumnOfTableByColumnId(table, "#colLeft", true, false);
        alignColumnOfTableByColumnId(table, "#colRight", false, false);

        // Align a table header left by columnId without invoking stage
        //        Platform.runLater(() -> {
        //            table.lookup("#colLeft").lookupAll(".column-header > .label").forEach(label -> {
        //                ((Label) label).setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        //            });
        //        });

        // Align only the table header "Left" to left by columnId
        //        Platform.runLater(() -> {
        //            stage.getScene().lookup("#colLeft").lookupAll(".column-header > .label").forEach(label -> {
        //                ((Label) label).setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        //            });
        //        });

        // Align only the table header "Left" to left by label text
        //        Platform.runLater(() -> {
        //            ArrayList<Node> headerNodes = new ArrayList<>(table.lookupAll(".column-header > .label"));
        //            for (Node headerNode : headerNodes) {
        //                Label headerLabel = ((Label) headerNode);
        //                if (headerLabel.getText().equals("Left")) {
        //                    headerLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        //                }
        //            }
        //        });

        // Align all table headers to left
        //        Platform.runLater(()->{
        //            table.lookupAll(".column-header > .label").forEach(node -> {
        //                System.out.println(node);
        //                ((Label) node).setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        //            });
        //        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(table, 500, 200);
        stage.setTitle("Table Column Alignment");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void alignColumnOfTableByColumnId(
            TableView<RowData> table,
            String columnIdWithHashTag,
            boolean alignLeft,
            boolean alignOnlyHeader) {

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            Pos alignment = alignLeft
                    ? Pos.CENTER_LEFT
                    : Pos.CENTER_RIGHT;
            String alignmentCells = alignLeft
                    ? "center-left"
                    : "center-right";

            table.lookup(columnIdWithHashTag).lookupAll(".column-header > .label").forEach(label -> {
                ((Label) label).setAlignment(alignment);
            });
            if (!alignOnlyHeader) {
                table.getScene().getStylesheets().add("data:text/css;base64," +
                        Base64.getEncoder()
                                .encodeToString((columnIdWithHashTag + ".table-cell {-fx-alignment: " + alignmentCells + "}")
                                        .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
            }
        });
    }


    private <T, V> TableColumn<T, V> buildTableColumn(
            String columnId,
            String title,
            Function<T, V> beanPropertyGetter) {

        TableColumn<T, V> tableColumn = new TableColumn<T, V>(title);
        tableColumn.setId(columnId);
        tableColumn.setCellValueFactory((cellDataFeatures) -> {
            T bean = cellDataFeatures.getValue();
            V beanPropertyValue = beanPropertyGetter.apply(bean);
            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<V>(beanPropertyValue);
        });
        return tableColumn;
    }

    public static void main(
            final String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there some way of extending the "table.lookupAll(...)" Selector to filter a particular ID?

Comment: Give me 5 minutes.

Comment: Also: now I have a "setStyle(...)" on the Right Column to position the Rows right & the nodeLabel.setAlignment(...) to position the Header on the right. Maybe there is ONE place to do both?

Comment: P.S. greetings from the sunny Odenwald :-)

Comment: Dann können wir uns auch auf Deutsch unterhalten. :D

Comment: Ja, das geht. Gerade so.

Comment: Please take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: You have now one single method, which can align a column in a table to left or to right. To that, you can specify, if you want to only align the header, or the complete columns.

Comment: The Egg-Laying-Wool-Milk-Sow! Thanks

Comment: Please mark my answer as approved, so that others can see it too! :)

Comment: Gesagt. Getan. :-)